# How do I say "right at that time"?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

I'm trying to explain a situation I was in recently in written Chinese. How would I say "Luckily, right at that time Mark heard my voice" 
Would it simply be 
幸亏， 她正好那时候听到我的声音，马上叫了起来“

Thanks for helping out! I'm most interested in how to say "Right at that time" in different contexts

Comment: Apart from other answers, don't forget '当初'

Answer (score 3):

"right at that time" == "剛好", "當時"

"Luckily, right at that time Mark heard my voice" => "幸好當時 Mark 聽見我的聲音(呼叫)"

Comment: Henry, two quick questions, 
So 
1. I know that 当时 literally  means at that time, but I'm trying to imply RIGHT at that time (as in it was a coincidence) would 当时 still work in this context? 

2. Why did you change 幸亏 to 幸好？

Comment: (1) "當時" also means "right at that time".  There is no need to say "正好那時候".  (2) For "幸虧"vs "幸好", it is just a matter of taste.  You may refer to https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=420044861383271 for a more detailed discussion.

Comment: I think using 湊巧 is better for what you have in mind, in the sense that it was a coincidence. Example: 當小女孩在窗口跌出去時，湊巧有民警經過， 衝上前把她接住。

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the context, 正好 might work for you also.

> [modif: 正 just + 好 good]
>
> 2 chance to, by coincidence
>
> 我正好那天下午没课, 可以陪她进城。
>
> Wǒ zhènghǎo nà tiān xiàwǔ méi kè, kěyǐ péi tā jìnchéng.
>
> It happened that I did not have class that afternoon, so I could go to town with her.
>
> -*Tuttle Learners*

This is more of a "just as it happens" kind of phrase but that could also totally fit your, "right at that time," depending on the, specific, context, of course. If you mean in the sentence that mark, just happened to - by chance (maybe you called him many times and on the last try...) heard your voice then 正好 can work here also.

Answer (score 2):

There's always the jukuu method: Go to jukuu.com (or youdao or icba) and type in "right at that time" or "just then" or similar phrases. You will see a wide variety of Chinese and English equivalent sentences.

Answer (score 1):

I would write the sentence as "幸亏， 她**那时(候)恰巧**听到我的声音，马上叫了起来“

Answer (score 0):

- 炒菜的时候，在"正确的时间"放盐。
- 在”正确的时间“遇见了正确的人，然后与他谈恋爱结婚了。